# UDP File upload to Windows Azure Media Services

Tags: azure

I'm trying to setup a video file upload using UDP protocol onto Windows Azure Media Services. I have not found any code sample or documentation to give me a headstart. Could somebody help me on this matter and provide me some code sample or a documentation or the concept?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Services is still [a preview feature](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/preview/). UDP will only be available [in the RTM release](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/windows-azure-media-services-preview-for-developers/):

> By the RTM release, Media Services will offer integration with partner
>   components to provide fast UDP (User Datagram Protocol) upload
>   solutions.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Azure Media Services is a platform as a service which uses Azure as the backend.  Specifically, it uses Azure Storage.  If you are using the .Net Media Services SDK to upload, then you may not notice that it is wrapping the AzStorage SDK calls for transfer.  If you are using the REST directly, you will notice that any PUT calls are heading straight for your storage account.  In both of these cases, all Media Services is doing it providing the SAS URLs for uploading to the backend storage.

At this time, AzStorage supports only HTTP PUT for uploads.

In addition, Azure has recently on-boarded a 3rd party solution for fast uploading, look for Aspera in the marketplace.  Note that this is a tiered subscription service and may require the purchase of client-side software (same model as Amazon S3, incase your doing side-by-side comparisons).
I did a full walk-through a few months ago on my blog:
http://blog-ndrouin.azurewebsites.net/?p=561
The blog needs a bit of maintenance since the service is no longer in preview, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :) I did a lot of research on this and I did read your blog on this topic earlier! Its a mighty great job!